Hollywood movie with Paul Walker as a cop who finds gold and goes to Heaven
I need one movie's name, in which Paul Walker plays a role. Here's the description:
In this movie Paul Walker plays the role of a policeman. He and another police officer find gold, after that they share it half and half. Paul hides that gold at his home. After that, in one operation his friend kills him, and gets the gold from his home below the tree.
In the other side after death, Paul goes to Heaven; there's a system there where they're given work as per their destiny. They offered him work and give him one old man to help him on Earth. They work to kill a monster on Earth and take his soul.
On Earth, a monster collecting all special kind of gold plans to live life once again as a human. They also go in heaven and get back all the gold. In the end, they set something up by collecting all the gold and try to revive all the dead people, but Paul Walker interrupts that work and tells the truth to his wife.

It wasn't Paul Walker but rather Ryan Reynolds. You described the plot of R.I.P.D. from 2013.

In Boston, the dirty cop Nick hides gold that he has stolen from drug-dealers with his partner Hayes in the backyard of his house. However, on the next morning, Nick tells Hayes that he will deliver the evidence to the police since he loves his wife Julia and he could not face her acting that way. Nick and Hayes are assigned to a raid against a dangerous gang and unexpectedly Hayes kills Nick. Nick is drawn by a tunnel and based on his previous experience in the police department, he is assigned in the afterlife by the Proctor to join the Rest in Peace Department that protects the living world from the undead and work with the old-fashioned agent Roy. Roy and Nick accidentally find that Hayes in plotting a scheme to revert the sense of the tunnel to the afterlife and bring the Apocalypse to Earth. 

It also starred Jeff Bridges, Kevin Bacon and Mary-Louise Parker. Here's the trailer:



